# SMB connections from OS X to Chromebook timing out after 15 minutes

Tags: network, macos, smb

I'm trying to transfer a bunch of large files from an old iMac running OS X Sierra (last supported version) to a Chromebook.  Using standard File Sharing (SMB) on the OS X end and Google's standard [Network File Share app on ChromeOS](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/access-network-share-files-chromebook/), I can mount the share, browse files and start transferring...  but problem is, after 15 minutes, the copy grinds to a halt and the mount becomes totally unresponsive ("An operation is taking too long, do you want to abort it?") until I log out and log back in again.

I suspect I'm hitting a timeout somewhere.  Any thoughts on what it is and where I can change it?  For comparison, Microsoft has [this list of SMB timeouts in Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/openspecification/smb-2-x-and-smb-3-0-timeouts-in-windows), but that's not terribly helpful here.  The copy is also absurdly slow, I manage to get only around 150 MB across before the connection dies even though both machines are on the same local network.

Also open to other ways to accomplish this, although I'd like to avoid round-tripping the files via the cloud if I can since we're talking gigs and gigs of data here.

Comment: It shouldn’t timeout in the middle of a copy.  If you’re doing this via WiFi, it’s going to be slow, but if it’s a poor connection, you may be losing the connection; that would cause the timeout.  I would copy things to a USB drive - it would be significantly faster than WiFi

Comment: It happens three times in a row after 15 min, so I don't think it's the wifi at fault here.  I'm using a USB key now but this will require about 10 round trips...

Comment: That doesn’t rule out WiFi latency issues